# A function to print the three highest numbers in an Int Array Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array: `let arr = [2900, 18120, 21566, 1028, 190, 59351, 2782, 2552, 89947, 3644, 12964, 3820, 14923, 7175, 541, 3109, 17679, 136, 26514, 237, 0, 7417, 1469, 664, 8230, 1319, 0, 0]`

I need a function to append the 3 highest numbers of `arr` into `newArr`

The result in the end should be:
`let newArr = [59351, 89947, 26514]`
and also another array containing the indexes of those 3 numbers from the first array
eg. 59351 would be at arr[5], 89947 would be at arr[8], 26514 would be at arr[18]
Therefore, another array should be created like: `let indexArr = [5, 8, 18]`

Comment: Please show what you've tried and where you're having problems. SO is not a code-writing or homework-solving service.

Comment: I don't even know where to begin. I tried using the max() function, but that only shows the highest value. I thought maybe I could remove the value of max() from the array, but I can't figure out how to get the index of it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can simply sort your collection indices by its elements values, get the first 3 indices, sort them and get its values:

```
let arr = [2900, 18120, 21566, 1028, 190, 59351, 2782, 2552, 89947, 3644, 12964, 3820, 14923, 7175, 541, 3109, 17679, 136, 26514, 237, 0, 7417, 1469, 664, 8230, 1319, 0, 0]

let indices = arr.indices.sorted(by: { arr[$0] > arr[$1] }).prefix(3).sorted()
let values = indices.map{arr[$0]}
print(indices) // [5, 8, 18]
print(values)  // [59351, 89947, 26514]
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit sloppy, but I would use the MAX value function in Swift to first identify the highest number

Example:

```
let numbers = [ 1, 42, 5, 21 ]
var maxNumber = Int()

for number in numbers {
    maxNumber = max(maxNumber, number as Int)
}

print("the max number is \(maxNumber)")   // will be 42
```

Take the end result of this function and append it to your newArr, but use the "RemoveAt" function to remove this number from your original array:

```
For only one element

if let index = animals.firstIndex(of: "chimps") {
    animals.remove(at: index)
}
print(animals) // ["cats", "dogs", "moose"]
```

Then, repeat this process to get the next highest value.